# Chrome Extension: Call a javascript function on the page, coming from the content script

Tags: google-chrome

I am trying to call a javascript function that exists on the page of the browser in my chrome extension's content script. Is this possible?

For example, the function "findCustomer()" is available on the page. Currently, if I run findCustomer("XXXXXXX") in the browser console, it will successfully return the customer's name. How will I be able to run this script from the content script?

I have code like this from the content script:

```
var customerId = "1234567";
alert(customerId); // This will display the customer ID on an alert
var customerName = findCustomer(customerId); // This is a javascript function on the page
```

I hope this is clear enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Content scripts execute in a special environment called an isolated world. They have access to the DOM of the page they are injected into, but not to any JavaScript variables or functions created by the page. https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#execution-environment

What you need to do is inject a `<script>` block into the page, like:

```
var injectedCode = '(' + function() {
   var customerId = "1234567";
   alert(customerId);
   var customerName = findCustomer(customerId);

} + ')();';

var script = document.createElement('script');
script.textContent = injectedCode;
(document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(script);
script.parentNode.removeChild(script);
```

Note: The `<script>` block is removed afterwards, since the code has been executed already by that point, and is no longer needed.